# W2UI 1.5rc1 not working fine with jQuery 3.2.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, w2ui

I'm trying to reproduce the example from W2UI 1.5rc-1 using an installed version of jQuery (3.2.1). I tried a grid, say. Nothing works fine. I switched to the exact jQuery version used in the example, i.e. 2.1.1 and everything ran fine.

Does someone know if W2UI 1.5rc1 is compatible with jQuery 3.2.1 and, if it is, what should I do to make this example work: [w2ui grid example](http://w2ui.com/web/get-started)

Comment: w2ui 1.5rc1 does indeed not play very well with jQuery 3.x - but you could try the nightly w2ui build (master branch). Related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828900/

Comment: Actually, I switched back to jQuery 2.x and it performs quite well. Thanks for the advice.